# UPS ground shipping fee on product page

Tags: magento-1.9

I was able to get the shipping fee using the below code on product page. But shipping fee were different from the checkout page. Please help? What is wrong with the code?

**UPS shipping fee on product page: 16.08**

**UPS shipping fee on checkout page: 29.78**

```
 $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId());
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(8344);;
        $country = "US";
        $zipId = "91203";
        $qty = 12;
        $quote->addProduct($_product, $qty);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId($country)->setPostcode($zipId); 
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();
        $_rates = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRatesCollection();
        $shippingRates = array();
        foreach ($_rates as $_rate):
                if($_rate->getPrice() > 0) {
                    $shippingRates[] =  array("Title" => $_rate->getMethodTitle(), "Price" => $_rate->getPrice());
                }
        endforeach;
```